# Automated way of sending a file to FTP without cmd

Tags: scripting, cmd, ftp

I have a scheduled task using Windows 7 to run a `.exe` file at a specific hour, which in-turn creates a `.txt` file and saves it in a folder. I am trying to write a script that will automatically send this `.txt` file to a FTP server without me using `cmd`.

I am working with this script thus far

```
open ftp.site.com
username
password
put c:\folder\file.txt
quit
```

Answer (score 0):

FTP doesn't require CMD. It can run in it's own console window.

`FTP /?` shows

```
  -s:filename     Specifies a text file containing FTP commands; the
                  commands will automatically run after FTP starts.
```

The script file contains exactly what you would type interactivly.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your current scheduled task runs a command like:

```
c:\folder\someapp.exe c:\folder\file.txt
```

Change that to

```
c:\folder\script.bat
```

Where the `c:\folder\script.bat` batch file will look like:

```
c:\folder\someapp.exe c:\folder\file.txt
ftp.exe -s:c:\folder\ftp.txt
```

And the `c:\folder\ftp.txt` will contains your FTP script:

```
open ftp.site.com
username
password
put c:\folder\file.txt
quit
```